# Session does not save in first request in laravel 5.2

Tags: session, laravel-5

My situation is weird.

I enclosed my routes in `Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () { /* Routes */ });`

I save my session using

```
Session::put('customer_id', $customer->id);
```

But when I refresh my browser. The session is gone. Then I save it again then refresh and works fine. It does not works in first save.

I'm checking it using

```
if (Session::has('customer_id)) {
 // Session saved.
} else {
 // Session not saved.
}
```

I also tried middlewareGroup but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Does your `$middlewareGroups` array in `app/Http/Kernel.php` include the following line?

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class
```

It would explain why the session isn't working.

The other thing to check is if the session is being overwritten elsewhere in your code. I.e. are you calling `Session::put`, anywhere else, and would `$customer->id` ever be `null` / `false` / `0`?

Comment: Yes, It has StartSession::class. Session::put is called only in my CustomerController. When I try to dd(Session::get('customer_id')) it has value but when I'm checking it using if(Session::has('customer_id')) it goes to else.

Comment: Also, $customer->id would never be null.